# How to get value from dropdown menu in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle toggle2" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Material Type
                </a>


                <div class="dropdown-menu menu2" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Mud</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cloth</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Thread</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Jute</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cotton</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Cane</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Bamboo</a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Can I get the value from the menu after selecting like following?

```
var email=document.getElementById('signUpEmail').value;
```

So that I can use this variable in ajax.

**Edit**
As @Timir suggest to use select then the menu is look like

```
<li class="nav-item">
<select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3" id="mydropdown">
  <option selected>Material Type</option>
  <option value="Mud">Mud</option>
  <option value="Cloth">Cloth</option>
  <option value="Thread">Thread</option>
  <option value="Jute">Jute</option>
  <option value="Cotton">Cotton</option>
  <option value="Can">Can</option>
  <option value="Bamboo">Bamboo</option>
</select>
</li>
```

Comment: are you looking for https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#select-menu ?

Comment: No you can't - it's a dropdown menu used for navigation rather than a select input. Check out [Bootstrap forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls) for a select dropdown

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get the value from the menu after selecting like following?

No, there are no input to retrieve their value.
but you can get the text inside the link like

```
$('.menu2 a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
    $(this).text()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a select, give it an id, then say:
    `$(“#mydropdown option:selected”).val();`

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was suggesting. Were you able to test the val() approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds for basically everything in JavaScript. Including this. Without using JQuery, you could add an event listener, or you could make an onlick within each option or anchor tag.
When you click on the drop down and set the option, it calls the function which sets the variable. So even though there is no input box... you are just setting a global variable. And then you utilize that variable as a part of a form or however you plan on using it.